# remove all collection items in collection when selected index of another collection changes

Tags: vb.net, collections, items, selectedindexchanged

EDIT: I was missing a simple command. See answer below.

I'm developing a front end .NET application that will replace the current one that my organization currently uses, on a temporary basis, that is intended to be simple to use for the newer employees. This is in regards to a ticketing system.
However, there is one function this application needs to perform, which is to 'classify' a problem that is reported.
I have 3 collections: 
`Service, Category, and Subcategory.`

I currently have my program set up to add in available options for category and subcategory based on the values entered in previously.

```
if Convert.ToString(cboxservice.selecteditem) = 15k Then
cboxCategory.Items.Add("15k Request")
End If
```

And the like. Cboxservice is a combobox. 
When someone selects 15k for Service, 15k Request should show up under Category.

However, if I were to go to another service, and have other objects added to the `Category` field, categories from both objects would be present.

I need to remove all items in the collection before adding different items to the collection.

Comment: Have you tried to use `cboxCategory.Items.Clear()`? That should remove all items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from NDJ, posted as comment.

> why not just use cboxCategory.Items.Clear() ? if you really want to do this in a while loop removing them one by one, don't rely on an exception (they are expensive) - it'd be better to While cboxCategory.Items.Count > 0 –  NDJ Dec 17 '14 at 8:44

Comment: why not just use cboxCategory.Items.Clear() ?  if you really want to do this in a while loop removing them one by one, don't rely on an exception (they are expensive) - it'd be better to While cboxCategory.Items.Count > 0

Comment: I am new to Visual Basic, and surprisingly enough, the book I had been reading did not cover that function, even though it went over several other properties of item collections. Thanks for letting me know about this, I was unable to find it by searching google, which is why I decided to ask here.